# Move Sheet to a Visible Excel Instance

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a userform in a workbook. When the workbook is opened this is the code that is run:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.Visible = False
UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

So now the user is only seeing the Userform. There is a button on the UserForm that creates a sheet in the invisible running workbook, and MY MAIN OBJECTIVE:

(1) Open a new instance of Excel

(2) Set the **new** instance of Excel as Visible (`Application.Visible = True`)

(3) Move the sheet from the invisible instance to the new created visible one.

This is the code I tried running without success:

```
Sub Move()

' Check if there is a sheet named "Data Sheet"
For Each s In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
If Not s.Name <> "Data Sheet" Then

' if true then create new excel instance
    Dim oXLApp As Object, wb As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set oXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    oXLApp.Visible = True
    Set wb = oXLApp.Workbooks.Add

'move the sheet "Data Sheet" to new workbook
    s.Move Before:=wb.Sheets(1)

'delete all sheets in new workbook except "Data Sheet"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        With wb
        For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Data Sheet" Then ws.Delete
        Next
        End With
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If
Next s

End Sub
```

I managed to move the sheet to a new workbook but within the same invisible excel instance using the below code:

```
Sub Move2()

Dim newWb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each s In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If Not s.Name <> "To Do" Then

        Dim sheetName As String
        sheetName = s.Name

        Set newWb = Workbooks.Add
        s.Move Before:=newWb.Sheets(1)

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        With newWb
        For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "To Do" Then ws.Delete
        Next
        End With
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    End If
Next s

End Sub
```

What is my mistake and what is a good workaround?

Comment: Do you really need a new instance of Excel or can you get away with visible and invisible Windows??

Comment: Mmm.... Frankly, I am not really after a new Excel instance as much as having the original Workbook remain running invisible while the new one has to be displayed to the user. What do you suggest?

Comment: "*This is the code I tried running without success:*" this tells us nothing.  Tell us what happens when you try to use it including any errors and what's wrong with the result.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I get a "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error". Any ideas?

Comment: @RBarryYoung Actually not sure which line is rte-1004 as nothing is highlighted when I get the error. What do you suggest I do?

Comment: try using debugging.  Put a breakpoint on the first line of the routine and then step through the routine until the error occurs.

Comment: Found an error in my answer. I have updated the answer. You may have to refresh the page to see it...

Comment: Ah yes. My mistake. You cannot move a sheet to a new instance of Excel.

Comment: If your file is saved then I have an alternative

Comment: Actually my file isn't saved. It is a Sheet that is created through the userform and moved outside to new a visible instance of Excel to keep the instance running the userform invisible. But I am open to a workaround.

Comment: One moment. testing the new code before posting :)

Comment: Why not just hide all sheets except the one you want? or a copy of the one you want? Why does it have to be in another workbook? Either loop all sheets in the workbook and set the `Visible` property to `xlSheetVeryHidden` if the name of the sheet is not the one you want visible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, you cannot move a worksheet to a different instance of Excel. Here is one workaround.

We will use the `.SaveCopyAs` method to save a copy of the existing workbook. You can read more about `.SaveCopyAs` [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835014.aspx)

**Logic**

1. Save a copy of the existing workbook using `.SaveCopyAs` in user's temp directory.
2. Open the copy in a new instance of excel and delete unwanted sheets.
3. <**Optional Step**> Re-Save the file (If required) at a new location as `.xlsx` to remove all macros.

**Code (TRIED AND TESTED)**

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function GetTempPath Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetTempPathA" _
(ByVal nBufferLength As Long, ByVal lpBuffer As String) As Long

Private Const MAX_PATH As Long = 260

Dim TempFile As String

Sub MoveSheet()
    Dim oXLApp As Object, wb As Object, ws As Object

    TempFile = TempPath & "MyFile.xlsm"

    On Error Resume Next
    Kill TempFile
    On Error GoTo 0

    ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs TempFile

    Set oXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    Set wb = oXLApp.Workbooks.Open(TempFile)

    oXLApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Data Sheet" Then ws.Delete
    Next

    '~~> Optional step to re save the file as xlsx
    wb.SaveAs "C:\MyNewFile.xlsx", 51

    oXLApp.DisplayAlerts = True

    oXLApp.Visible = True
End Sub

'~~> Function to get the user's temp directory
Function TempPath() As String
    TempPath = String$(MAX_PATH, Chr$(0))
    GetTempPath MAX_PATH, TempPath
    TempPath = Replace(TempPath, Chr$(0), "")
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. When I am trying it with `Options Explicit` I am getting  "Compile error: Variable not defined" for **s** when I try without `Options Explicit` I get a Run-time error '1004' (Move method of Worksheet class failed) for `s.Move Before:=wb.Sheets(1)` [Screenshot](http://im38.gulfup.com/GH8Ib.png). Any idea what's causing the error?

Comment: Thanks, but now I am getting another error: "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error" [SCREEENSHOT](http://im31.gulfup.com/6ddmg.png). Is it maybe because it can't identify the new instance?

Comment: Still getting a "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error" :(    [SCREEN](http://im33.gulfup.com/tSmHG.png)

Comment: That is becuase maybe you have previous instances left running in task manager. Save your file and close Excel and then before you restart it, check in task manager that there is no excel instance left behind.

Comment: I will look at the file after you try what I suggested in my previous comment.

Comment: Well you are partially right. What happens is that I open the file and run the code, I get the run-time error. So I close the file and then open it again, only this time 2 files open: (1) The file I double clicked **and** the (2) MyFile.xlsm with the "Data Sheet" in it. Not sure why this is happening though.

Comment: Hmm, I just tested your above attached file and it works just fine for me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46089/discussion-between-user1350263-and-siddharth-rout)